# Is "regardless" a word I shouldn't use?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is it true that "regardless" is a word I shouldn't use because it is obsolete? If it is, what shall I use instead?

Comment: What makes you suspect the word? You need to provide some reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Says who? *Regardless* is a perfectly standard word in current use.

I suspect you are confusing it with *irregardless*, which is often used for *regardless* or *irrespective*, and may originate either as a portmanteau of those, or as a double-negative of *regard*.

That's much more controversial, considered wrong by many, and a pet hate of quite a few. They though wouldn't say it was obsolete so much as that it had never been a "proper" word.

Certainly, avoid *irregardless*, at least in formal writing, but there's no such opprobrium applied to *regardless*.